# How to add folders with C++ files to a NetBeans project?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I had copied folder to my project folder with one cpp file and set of headers. It appeared in project view. How I understand this means they was added to project (if I can see they in project view). Right?

But `undefined reference to` ((

Then I found that they does not exist in `logicalFolder` of `nbproject/configurations.xml`. I had added it manualy (found solution for this from stackoverflow: [Netbeans-specific C++ error Undefined reference to XXX - (Solution posted)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13024723/3809945)). How I understand this is not normal behaviour. Right?

```
<logicalFolder name="SourceFiles"
               displayName="Source Files"
               projectFiles="true">
  <itemPath>src/jsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp</itemPath>
  ...
```

Clean and build. As result in output I see that all files compiled except cpp file from my added folder:

```
src/jsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp
```

No any mentions about `jsoncpp.cpp` in compile output pane. All files compiled  (in `src` folder) except `jsoncpp.cpp` (in `src/jsoncpp` folder).

Could you help me how to fix this?

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.8.0_131; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.131-b11
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_131-b11
System: Linux version 3.13.0-119-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
User directory: /home/xxx/.netbeans/8.2
Cache directory: /home/xxx/.cache/netbeans/8.2
```

P.S. Also on the Navigator pane of `src/jsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp` I see `"Limited assistance (no associated project)"`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to go directly to the `nbproject` directory and make changes there. Instead:

1. Open `Projects` pane
2. Right click on project name - popup menu will be shown
3. Click `Add Existing Items from Folders...` button in this menu - a popup window will appear
4. Click `Add Folder` button to choose a folder - a selection popup window will appear
5. Select the folder you want and click the `Select` button
6. Click `Add` to add the folder to your project

All the files from this folder will be added to your project. If you want to add files one by one you can use the `Add Existing Item` button in the popup menu.

The added folder will be shown on the `Files` pane as a **logical folder** with name, consisting of your project name, dash and the absolute folder path. You can use this logical folder to easily access its files. Logical folders don't have to be in the project directory - they can be anywhere in your filesystem.

Comment: Did not help :-(
1) Create new `"C/C++ Application"` project with `"uncheck create main file"` and select folder of project;
2) `"Add existing Items from folders"` and select all files in subfolder `"src"` including jsoncpp. All files/folders was added;
3) Add libraries and select `"C++ 11"` compiler;
4) Add `"src/jsoncpp"` to `"Build/C++ Compiler/Include Directories"`;
5) Add `"src/jsoncpp"` to `"General/Source Folders"`. Result: two entries `"src"` and `"src/jsoncpp"`;
6) Clean and build;
Result: same error. `"jsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp"` is exist in project view but did not compiled

Comment: After add `"src/jsoncpp"` I found that after closing properties dialog and reopen it I see that `"src/jsoncpp"` disappired in "General/Source Folders" and only `"src"` entry remain.

Comment: @AlexanderSymonenko - you are right, my answer isn't helpful, I'll edit it. But - I was able to add existing directories and/or files to my test project, and it was compiled OK

Comment: Ok. In any case thank you. I had reported issue: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=270895

Comment: Yahoo! All is works. I had used `"Add existing item"` for select all files and my jsoncpp folder instead `"Add existing item"` for files in `"src"` folder and `"Add existing items from Folders"` for `"src/jsoncpp"` folder. More detailed can be read in my additional comment in bug report. But in any case bug is exist )) You add item to `"General/Source folders"` and it disappears without any feedback/errors from GUI. Oh my brain. I'm beginning to regret that I had choose NetBeans instead Qt Creator for new project.

Comment: @AlexanderSymonenko - a majority of my NetBeans projects are actually `with existing sources` (with my own `Makefile`) - this is more flexible and shields me from NetBeans quirks